# Display [datetime] object in 24 hour format

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have some code that checks for a valid date, simple example:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact(
    '201809222130',
    'yyyyMMddHHmm',
    [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
)
```

This outputs:

```
Saturday, September 22, 2018, 9:30:00 PM
```

I'm trying to display the hour in 24h format, desired output:

```
Saturday, September 22, 2018, 21:30:00 PM
```

It is possible to display 24h format using the `Get-Date` Cmdlet, e.g.: `Get-Date -UFormat %R`, but I can't use this when creating a `[datetime]` object.

How can I display 24h format?

Comment: In c# you use myDate.ToString("HH:mm");

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't any reason you can't use `Get-Date` with the `[datetime]` object your code creates. For example:

```
$d = [datetime]::ParseExact(
    '201809222130',
    'yyyyMMddHHmm',
    [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
)

Get-Date $d -UFormat %R
```

You could also use the `.ToShortTimeString()` method:

```
$d.ToShortTimeString()
```

Or `.ToString` and specify the tokens:

```
$d.ToString('HH:mm')
```

Answer (score 11):

The PowerShell answer

Using get-date -format

HH is 24 hour

hh is 12 hour

get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss"

2021-04-12 183340

get-date -format "yyyy-MM-dd hhmmss"

2021-04-12 063340

Answer (score 2):

[Mark Wragg beat me to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49149426/5039142)!

To add to his answer, you are getting this output because of your region settings. On my machine, the same code returns:

```
22 September 2018 21:30:00
```

The reason for this is because my region settings look like this:

[image]

You could change your Global Region settings, but it's better to get it done with code.