# How to convert string to date in 24 hour format in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am having a string which contains 24 hr format.

I am trying to convert it to 24hrs format but it is not changing. below is my code.

```
$fromtime = '2018-03-28,23:37:50'
[datetime]$fromtime24hrFormat = ([datetime]$fromtime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm:ss")
$fromtime24hrFormat

Wednesday, March 28, 2018 11:37:50 PM
```

It shows in PM which is correct. But is it not possible to show it in 24 hr format?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149233/display-datetime-object-in-24-hour-format/49149501#49149501

Comment: Huh? You read a 24h format as datetime, then turn it to a string (using the same format) and then cast it to datetime for the second time. Why? Displaying a datetime-object will use your regional settings by default which is 12h+AM/PM. If you want to display it as 24h, use ex. `toString()` with the format you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're so close!

```
$fromtime = '2018-03-28,23:37:50'
[datetime]$fromtime24hrFormat = ([datetime]$fromtime)
$fromtime24hrFormat.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm:ss")
```

The problem is that your last line was effectively just dumping the **`datetime`** object to the output; which will use a default formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Did you want to add AM/PM to the original input? Try:

```
$fromtime = '2018-03-28,23:37:50'
$fromtime24hrFormat = [datetime]$fromtime
$fromtime24hrFormat.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm:ss tt")

2018-03-28,23:37:50 p.m.
```

*"p.m." vs PM is caused by my Norwegian regional settings*

Comment: I have tried this but I still get 12 hour returned.

$goingto = "C:\2"

        $latest = (Get-ChildItem $goingto -filter "*.cra" -Attributes !Directory | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | select -first 1)
        $FIlecreation = $FIlecreation = $latest.CreationTime

write-host $FIlecreation

Write-host  $FIlecreation.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

 [datetime]$fromtime24hrFormat = ([datetime]$FIlecreation)
Write-host $fromtime24hrFormat.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm:ss")

write-host $FIlecreation

Write-host  $FIlecreation.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")